# ORA-20003: You are not allowed to create partitioned tables in this database

Tags: oracle11g

I am getting this error when trying to create partitioned tables in oracle 11g .what privileges should I have to create partitioned tables?

Comment: What edition of the software do you have? Partitioning is only available in Enterprise Edition. If you have SE or XE you can't use it - it's not a privilege issue, it's a licensing issue.

Comment: If you're getting in EE then exactly what command are you using? Just twigged that you're getting a application range error number, not the ORA-00439 you'd get in XE (not sure about SE). I can only see [one reference to that exact message](https://community.emc.com/thread/127638?start=0&tstart=0); are you using that product?